# Pass enum class as parameter to method in java

Tags: java, enums

I have two different Enums:

```
public enum A { 
    mass(10); // many other values omitted for clarity

    private final int m;

    private A(int m) { this.m = m; }

    public int value() { return this.m; }

}

public enum B {
    mass(100); // many other values omitted for clarity

    private final int m;

    private B(int m) { this.m = m; }

    public int value() { return this.m; }
}
```

and want to pass enum class as parameter to my function. From other answers that I found on SO, it is suggested that I can pass Class, but I am not sure how to correctly detect and use A or B enum in the function body:

```
public int mass(Class<?> clazz) {
   // Is it the best way? How to avoid a bunch of ifs?
   if (clazz == A.class) return A.mass.value();
   if (clazz == B.class) return B.mass.value();
}
```

Comment: This seems really ugly and as if you shouldn't need to do it, but it should work just fine.

Comment: Why not just have `A` and `B` both implement an interface with a `getMass()` method?

Comment: Let's say A and B cannot be changed for some reason (for example, those enums are part of some external library I'm using). What's then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish buddy but you seem to be in need of polymorphism. Try using an interface with Enums like this:

```
public enum A implements MassProvider {
    MASS(10);
    private int mass;

    A(int mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMass() {
        return mass;
    }
}

public enum B implements MassProvider {
    MASS(100);
    private int mass;

    B(int mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMass() {
        return mass;
    }
}

public interface MassProvider {
    int getMass();
}

public static int mass(MassProvider p) {
    return p.getMass();
}
```

Basically instead of passing a class to the mass method you pass a MassProvider that is implemented by both enums.

Comment: It seems polymorphism is a way to go, but I am still not clear how to pass an instance of A or B to the mass(MassProvider p) function?

Comment: Just pass the A or B instance to the mass method. Since A and B implement MassProvider it'll just work.